# Apply a function rowwise in Rcpp/RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I have a function which takes a vector as input and outputs a scalar and I want to apply this function to a number of observations. The data is structured in a matrix (rows are the number of observations and columns the variables) and the function is:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double gaussianweight(arma::vec x, arma::mat H) {
  double c       = std::pow(2 * arma::datum::pi, -0.5 * x.n_rows);
  double s       = std::pow(arma::det(H), -1);
  arma::mat Hinv = arma::inv(H);

  return(c * s * std::exp(-0.5 * arma::dot(Hinv * x, Hinv * x)));
}
```

to every *row vector* of a `arma::mat X`. How would I do that efficiently? A loop that lopps over the rows of X or are there better solutions? I use R for the most time and really got used to avoid loops whenever it is possible. I tried the `.each_row()` operations but had no luck...

Comment: Hi, my instinct is to say look into the rowise function on dplyr, but can you please provide a reprex

Comment: the thing is that is that I want (have) to outsource it in c++. It is no problem to use ``apply(X, 2, gaussianweight, H) in base R but since I have a lot of loops, I want to try to improve the speed by outsourcing it to c++

Comment: you can maybe do parallel computation if you need even more speed, but I personally don't know if your code can be made to work with a vector o vectors and a vector's

Comment: How did you apply each_row?

Comment: X.each_row( [](const vec& v ){ gaussianweight(v, H); } );